# Are questions about underwater search equipment suitable?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I just saw [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3430/why-single-underwater-robotic-submarine-bluefin-21-is-being-deployed-in-mh370-se), which asks about why only one Bluefin-21 is being deployed to search the area.

While the OP has mentioned it in the context of MH370, isn't this more of a question about the effectiveness of underwater search operations, and potential reasons for a particular strategy?

Would you consider this question as on-topic for Aviation or not?

Comment: I don't see any other site where it could be on topic (maybe robotics.SE or newly launched earthscience.SE)

Comment: In addition, these searches are led by political motives and several other factors, which may not be released to general public.

Answer (score 2):

My first impulse in seeing that question was to flag it as opinion-based.

It asks about a specific reason (not a fact) about a reaction to a specific recent event, it either asks us to provide our opinions on how such decision has been made or it risks being too broad creating a ginormous list of all possible factors that (might) have been taken into account.

As @Farhan mentions in the comments, these decisions have political background undisclosed to the general public.

**EDIT :**

now that an answer is there, I am even more convinced that it is off-topic, there is nothing related to aviation.

Answer (score -1):

As an aside to @Federico's answer (generalising, rather than talking about this specific question) — in my opinion questions about underwater search equipment are on-topic here.

The [search-and-rescue](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-and-rescue) tag should be used on such questions.